# Can I check the value of my macro?

Tags: c

I have defined my buffer with a specific size, and if this size is too low, I'd like to send an error message stating that the buffer should be equal, or higher to this specific size.

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 10
```

Knowing that my comparison is done with a variable (int) called "ret" (that represents the value the buffer should be equal or higher to), how can I verify that my buffer is big enough?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

amm... how about:

```
if(BUFF_SIZE >= yourMinAllowedSize)
{
   // Your code
}
else
{
    //Error message
}
```